# google cloud sql instance in limbo

Tags: google-cloud-sql

One of our google cloud sql instance is in limbo since several hours. First it rejected the communication packages. I then tried to restart it and that is the state the instance has since a few hours. There is no way to create a replica or get another instance running with the same data and thus we're standing still.

Inspecting the logs in the dev console reveal the following entries.

```
I 2015-12-16 12:12:18.976 2015-12-16 11:12:18 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
I 2015-12-16 12:12:18.976 2015-12-16 11:12:18 0 [Note]  (mysqld 5.6.26-log) starting as process 847865 ...
I 2015-12-16 12:12:18.979 2015-12-16 11:12:18 847865 [ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
I 2015-12-16 12:12:18.979 2015-12-16 11:12:18 847865 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Even worse, since it is a cloud sql  instance and since it is in limbo, there is no way to change/influence/fix any setting. 
Help is highly appreciated.

Update: The instance is back alive.

Comment: Could you please send an email to cloud-sql@google.com and provide your instance name? We can help you diagnose the issue there. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tianzhou, thanks for your response. The instance is back again and I also reached out to the address you provided me.